# AGOL Python Api - Modify Symbology of a Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-online-webmap

I want to modify the JSON properties of a Feature Layer hosted online to display a certain field in symbology. I am able to access the JSON properties, even the property itself but when I call an .update_definition on it I get :

```
AttributeError: 'PropertyMap' instance has no attribute 'update_definition'
```

Here is my code :

```
item = gis.content.get('XXXXXXXXXXXXX')
print(item)
flc = FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(item)
print(flc)
print(flc.manager.properties)
#print(flc.manager.properties.maxRecordCount)
#flc.manager.update_definition({'maxRecordCount':2000})#works
print(flc.manager.properties.layers[0].drawingInfo.renderer.field1)
flc.manager.properties.layers[0].drawingInfo.renderer.update_definition({'field1':'AQROUTES_2'})
```

What is weird to me is that I am able to modify the maxRecordCount attribute (commented out) but not the drawingInfo.

Has anyone ever had success doing this?